# IBM Watson error: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant, watson-discovery

I am trying to integrate Watson discovery into my Watson assistant chatbot by following an IBM course on EDX. I followed the course instructions but when I add Watson discovery to my chatbot my web hooks returned this:

> {"result":{"err":"Access is denied due to invalid credentials."}

When I expected something like this:

> {"result":{["courses":"Data Science", "courses":"Ibm"]}

My `serverless.yml` file looks something like this:

```
custom:
  package: lab4
  discovery:
    username: apikey
    password: aaaaaaaaa
    environmentId: aaaaaaa
    collectionId: aaaaaaa
    url: https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api
    intent: course_recommendation # DO NOT CHANGE
```

Could anyone please guide me to where I went wrong and please tell me if you need to see any other code.
Thank you.

Comment: Without stating the obvious, the error message would seem to clearly indicate that there's a problem with the credentials... Are you 100% certain that you've specified everything as indicated in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicates the API Key that you are using is incorrect for the endpoint that you are using. This normally indicates that either your key is incorrect or that you are using an incorrect url.

I am guessing that you have only recently created a Discovery service instance, in which case I would expect the endpoint to look something like:

```
https://api.us-south.discovery.watson.cloud.ibm.com
```

or

```
https://api.eu-gb.discovery.watson.cloud.ibm.com
```

depending on where you deployed your instance.

You can determine what your endpoint should be, from the someplace you got your APIKey. If you can't see your endpoint there, then I suspect that you will also have the wrong APIKey.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. However there is a new problem, it now says:
```{"result":{"err":"No courses are found"}```

courses is the name of my watson discovery

Comment: Actually I solved it, thank you so much for your help. I solved the error above by changing my parameter key to ```input``` and not ```Input``` :) .
Unfortunately I cannot upvote your answer because of my low reputation points.